# Ionic scroll won't fire on load with $getByHandle()

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to scroll down to delegate-handle="start" with ionic on load. When i try to run it, i get this message in console.

```
Delegate for handle "small" could not find a corresponding element with delegate-handle="small"! scrollTop() was not called!
```

Possible cause: If you are calling scrollTop() immediately, and your element with delegate-handle="small" is a child of your controller, then your element may not be compiled yet. Put a $timeout around your call to scrollTop() and try again.

My code looks like this, can somebody maybe see what is wrong?

```
$timeout(function() {
     $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('start').scrollTop();

}, 10);
```

If i use $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(), it will scroll to the bottom, so it must be a problem with the specific function.

The html code

```
     <ion-view title="Kalender">
   <ion-content>
    <ion-list ng-repeat="activity in calendar">

       <div class="item item-divider" ng-show="activity.date_divider != null" data-year="{{activity.year}}">
        <div class="header-divider-small">{{activity.year}}</div>
        <div class="header-divider">{{activity.date_divider}}</div>
      </div>

        <div class="item item-icon-right calendar" ng-show="activity.date_divider == null">
            <span class="header">{{activity.name}}</span>
              <br />
              <span class="text">{{activity.time}} - {{activity.place}}</span>
              <a class="button button-icon icon {{activity.icon}} right not-selected"></a>
        </div>


    </ion-list>
    <div delegate-handle="start"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your scroll area? There has to be the `delegate-handle="start"` attribute on your <ion-scroll> or <ion-content> element.

Comment: @JeremyWilken - i have updated my question with the html code. I put a delegate-handle in the bottom of the page, under the list. But maybe I can't place it in a div?

Answer (score 11):

`Ionic 1.0.0-beta14` has some strange issue with `getByHandle()` so you can do it this way:

```
$timeout(function() {
    var startHandle = _.find($ionicScrollDelegate._instances, function (s) {
        return s.$$delegateHandle === "start";
    });
    startHandle.scrollTop();
});
```

[Solution source at forum.ionicframework.com](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/slidebox-getbyhandle-not-working-in-modal/13590/11)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a misunderstanding about what the delegate handle does here. Delegate handle is a way to name scroll/content containers. Think of it like a way to give your `<ion-content>` container a unique name that can be later used with the service. It is possible to have multiple `<ion-content>` containers on a single view, and this is why the naming is necessary. If you only have one scroll area or don't specify the handle, then it just uses the first view it finds.

You want to scroll to a particular place in the application, which is the job of `$ionicScrollDelegate.anchorScroll('element-id');`. Take a look at your code here with some modifications. I've put the delegate handle in the correct place, and then use the anchorScroll method to automatically scroll to that ID in the page.

**Markup**

```
<ion-view title="Kalender">
   <ion-content delegate-handle="kalendar">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="activity in calendar">

       <div class="item item-divider" ng-show="activity.date_divider != null" data-year="{{activity.year}}">
        <div class="header-divider-small">{{activity.year}}</div>
        <div class="header-divider">{{activity.date_divider}}</div>
      </div>

        <div class="item item-icon-right calendar" ng-show="activity.date_divider == null">
            <span class="header">{{activity.name}}</span>
              <br />
              <span class="text">{{activity.time}} - {{activity.place}}</span>
              <a class="button button-icon icon {{activity.icon}} right not-selected"></a>
        </div>


    </ion-list>
    <div id="start"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller**

```
$timeout(function() {
   $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('kalendar').anchorScroll('start');
}, 10);
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sence. But how can I invoke this without a hash in the url? Is there a way to create a hash when data has been loaded? Sorry - i'm just starting on ionic and angularjs:-)

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need to happen here, do you want to scroll to a place after data loads? Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes that is what I want:-D I have a calender with dates for the whole year (2014). So if we are in december 2014 as we are now, I would like it to scroll down to december 2014 instead of showing the start of the calendar (januy 2014):-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Specify the dalegate-handler in ion-content

<ion-view title="Kalender">
    <ion-content delegate-handle="start">
        <ion-list ng-repeat="activity in calendar">
        <div class="item item-divider" ng-show="activity.date_divider != null" data-year="{{activity.year}}">
            <div class="header-divider-small">{{activity.year}}</div>
            <div class="header-divider">{{activity.date_divider}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-icon-right calendar" ng-show="activity.date_divider == null">
             <span class="header">{{activity.name}}</span>
             <br />
             <span class="text">{{activity.time}} - {{activity.place}}</span>
             <a class="button button-icon icon {{activity.icon}} right not-selected"></a>
        </div>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Scroll top can be achieved by forgetting the scroll position which can be achieved by using

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    var delegate = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('start');
    delegate. forgetScrollPosition();
});
```

Use

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('start').scrollTop(); //To scroll to Top.
```

As I noticed `delegate-handle` won't work if used with `overflow-scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way:

```
$scope.scrollHandle = some-handle-value-that-you-want-to-use;

$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function () {

    $timeout(function () {
        scrollView = $ionicScrollDelegate._instances.filter(function (s) {
            if (!s.$$delegateHandle) return false;
            return $parse(s.$$delegateHandle.slice(2, -2))
                (angular.element(s.element).scope()) == $scope.scrollHandle;
        })[0];

    }).then(function () {
        scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0, false);
    });
});
```

In the template:

```
delegate-handle="{{scrollHandle}}"
```

EDIT:

This doesn't work anymore, check this answer for new solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123613/1630623

Comment: It looks like they fixed it, but still needs to be done in $ionicView.loaded